# Android: UI state dependent on serice (music player scenario)

Tags: android, android-service

I have an app which starts a service (using startService). This service performs something similar to playing music. It can be seen as an indefinite work which has to be stopped manually through my activity.

In my activity, I would like to use a "switch" to show the state of the service (running/not running). This is somewhat like a play/pause button on a music player.

When my activity is created, how would I create the UI (switch) to be consistent with the service state (running/not running)?

I don't this using saveInstanceState/restore... will work. My app could be killed completely and the service will service and I will not receive the instance state once started again.

I don't this using SharedPreferences/DB will work. My process could have been killed and at next start, the app would think that the service is running.

The only stable solution I've been able to come up with is to ask the service (maybe through binding) if it is doing work or not.

Would this work? How would you do this?

Answer (score 0):

Binding to the service would work (we have this exact scenario with a background audio player and resolved it that way).

Be mindful that [binding is asynchronous](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html), though.

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware. Can I do anything smarter than (1) Accept the UI to be responding before state is received from service or (2) Block UI until state is received from service?

Comment: I would go with (3) Don't display this particular UI component until the binding is complete and you have obtained the status. Purely from experience, binding is asynchronous but "fast".

Comment: Good idea. Or maybe disable it so user cannot press it.